# should be easy xml deserialization

Tags: c#, xml

I don't know what i'm doing wrong here, but everytime I try to deserialize my xml object, all the values come out null.
I know the path is correct, the code IS loading the document correctly, but when I try to deserialize it, everything's null.
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

My xml structure:

```
<settings>
    <settingsList>
        <setting>
            <name>ConnectionString</name>
            <value>testconnectionstring</value>
        </setting>
    </settingsList>
</settings>
```

Settings.cs:

```
[DataContract]
[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "settings")]
public class Settings
{
    [DataMember]
    [XmlElement("settingsList")]
    public List<Setting> SettingsList { get; set; }
}
```

Setting.cs:

```
[DataContract]
[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "setting")]
public class Setting
{
    [DataMember]
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    [XmlElement("value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And finally, my deserialization code:

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(docPath);
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Settings));
var settings = (Settings)serializer.Deserialize(xml.CreateReader());
```

Comment: If you're using DataContract attributes, shouldn't you be using a DataContractSerializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use XmlArray and XmlArrayItem:

```
    [DataMember]
    [XmlArray("settingsList")]
    [XmlArrayItem("setting")]
    public List<Setting> SettingsList { get; set; }
```

Comment: Bless you!  This worked!  I've done this so many times, and I've not needed to use XmlArray before.

Comment: Strange. I copied and pasted the original code into a Console app and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @Andrew - Did it work all the way through to name and value values?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the issue is here:`[XmlRoot(ElementName = "setting")]` in setting.cs.I think it must be `[XmlRoot(ElementName = "settingList")]`coz setting list is the parent of all settings.
Take a try.